# How to copy a db data to another db using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to copy a db data to another db in MYSQL using Procedure.
sourceDB and DesginationDB structure is same.
ie,
  same tables with same columns.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear at all. Any chance you can take another stab at it?

Comment: I have a sourceDB and DesignationDB.  Data of sourceDB has copy to DesignationDB through Procedure using MYSQL